# Is it possible to change radio button color in Gtk?

Tags: python, css, gtk, glade

I'm creating a Gtk application with Glade, Python and Css and I would like to know if I can change the color of the circle in a radio button.

I have tried all css properties of radio buttons but none of them worked

Thanks!

Comment: circle inside the radio button is an image "-gtk-icon-source".. "radio:checked {
-gtk-icon-source: builtin;
} " will change it to a black circle

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the answer, this is the code you need if you want to use a custom image on a radio button:

```
radio:checked {
    -gtk-icon-source: url("path_to_the_file");
}
```